# Haskell's subset operation doesn't give me all results, only part of it is shown?

Tags: haskell, filter, list-comprehension

I've learning LYAH and the last question from Chapter 1 is to find `a`,`b` and `c` where `(a,b,c)` form a right triangle, and their sum is 24. `a`,`b`,`c` are all `Int`s.

So I have the code below(not the same from the book).

```
Prelude> [(a,b,c)|c<-[1..10],b<-[1..10],a<-[1..10],a^2+b^2==c^2,a+b+c==24]
[(8,6,10),(6,8,10)]
```

I expect to get all possible combinations like

```
[(8,6,10),(6,8,10),(8,10,6),(6,10,8),(10,6,8),(10,8,6)]
```

Why only part of it is shown? I tried different versions of ghci but got same results. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You guard for `a^2 + b^2 == c^2`, but for e.g. `(8, 10, 6)`, it is not true that `8^2 + 10^2 == 6^2`. Hence, they are not included in the result.